# Unable to connect SQL Server with ODBC drivers on linux

Tags: sql-server, oracle, connection, odbc

I have install the driver odbc 2.3.0 on linux by this reference: https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/confirmation.aspx?id=28160

All these steps work correctly.

This is my configation:

SERVER:

- Oracle server is on linux
- SQL Server is on windows

SQL Server:

My login and password are the same. It's: demo
When I use cmd and I use the command: "ipconfig", I can get my IP
My IP is: 192.168.0.106

This is how I do my connection manually and it work:

[image: Connexion manually]

After the installation, i have configure my files odbinst.ini and odbc.ini

This is my file odbcinst.ini:

[image: odbcinst.ini]

This is my file odbc.ini:

[image: odbc.ini]

This is where my driver is download:

[image]

My instance name is MSSQLSERVER and TCP-IP and listen all are enable:

[image: Instance-name, tcp-ip and listen all]

Dynamic port is blank and static port is 1433:

[image: dynamic port]

As you see, I can be connect on localhost with the command line:

```
sqlcmd -S 192.168.0.106 -d demo -U demo -P demo
```

[image: command line connexion]

But, I can't connect with my Oracle server on putty with this command line:

```
isql MSSQLSERVER -v
```

[image: Server command line]

Why it don't work?

- The server is start
- Allows remotely connexion is enable
- I have add port 1433 in firewall setting
- I tried to disable the firewall, nothing change

Something is wrong in my configuration?

Comment: Can you see the connection attempt on SQL Server? Does the host `agencesprov` actually have access to the instance SQL Server is on in the networks fire wall rules (not the host)?

Comment: Where can i see that on SQl Server 2019?

Comment: The attempt? In the logs (I doubt you will but worth checking). For the latter, with your network administrator.

Comment: I test on a local SQL Server, so i am the administrator ! But i don't know where i can go to see the attempt.

Comment: In the SQL Server logs, like I said ok the prior comment.

Comment: yeah but i don't know how to go till Logs. Next time i work is 
Thursday, i will look that and give u an answer

Comment: I don't see any log

Comment: I didn't think you would, tbh. I'd check with your network administrator then

Comment: I can telnet the ip adress with the port 1433 so the port listen and i can be connect. The problem is from my oracle database. I have set up the DNS but i can't connect on my sqlServer.

Comment: It is suppose work on a localhost Sql Server?

Answer (score 0):

Problem reseolve :

Change sqlServer Localhost to SqlServer.

You can't connect 2 server if they are on localhost. You need an oracle SQL Server and SQlServer working not on LocalHost